# Is it possible to have excel circle the cell that contains today's date?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a big calendar spreadsheet that currently just highlights today's date with conditional formatting. However, I do not like any of the formats I could possibly apply and so I would love to be able to have something whereby a circle is drawn over the top of the cell with today's date in.

The way each day is laid out is so that (for example) A1 is the date itself in "dd" format and then A2 has the information in. The information is pulled through from an event data list so it has a formula in.

I have seen some stuff on this being possible with a VBA code but I am just not sure how to write that.

Thank you
Sam

Comment: I bet you could have a shape anchored at the corner of the cell with today’s date. Wish I could take a crack at this one

Comment: Does it have to be a circle, or could you use *.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous*?

Answer (score 3):

This will draw an oval round today's date. If today's date is not found, an error message will be shown:

```
Sub DrawOval()
    Dim cell As Range, circ As Shape

    Set cell = Sheet1.Cells.Find(Date, Sheet1.Range("A1"))

    If Not cell Is Nothing Then
        Set circ = Sheet1.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, 187.8, 37.2, 63.6, 24)
        With circ
            .Select
            Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
            .Top = cell.Top
            .Left = cell.Left
        End With

    Else
        MsgBox "Cell with today's date not found!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error"
    End If

End Sub
```

This assumes your worksheet name is `Sheet1`, so amend that accordingly. You can run this by adding a shape to your worksheet, and assigning this macro to it.

Comment: Just a thought (not looked at improving the maths on it) - change the Top, Left, Height and Width to: `.Top = cell.Top - (cell.Offset(-1).Height / 2)`, `.Left = cell.Left - (cell.Offset(, -1).Width / 4)`, `.Height = cell.Height + (cell.Offset(-1).Height / 2) + (cell.Offset(1).Height / 2)`, `.Width = cell.Width + (cell.Offset(, -1).Width / 4) + (cell.Offset(, 1).Width / 4)` so the circle extends into the neighbouring cells.

Comment: I believe you can avoid the `select` part of your code by just trimming down to `With circ  .ShapeRange. ...`